# What does & do in ruby (between integers)

Tags: ruby, syntax, operators

I would like to know what & does in the use case:

```
7 & 3 
   => 3

8 & 3
   => 0
```

Or as seen in the general use case:

```
 Integer & Integer
    => ??
```

I know that array & array2 gives the intersection between the two arrays, but I am unsure of exactly what is going on here when used with integers.

Comment: Hover over the "ruby" tag. Click on the ["info" link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/info) at the bottom of the popup. Enjoy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&` is bitwise AND which examines the two operands bit-by-bit and sets each result bit to `1` if both the corresponding input bits are `1`, and `0` otherwise. You can also think of it as bit-by-bit multiplication.

```
     111 (7)
AND  011 (3)
------------
=    011 (3)

    1000 (8)
AND 0011 (3)
------------
=   0000 (0)
```